# Errror when resizing Jpeg image using python for machine learning

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, jpeg, rgba

I am trying to test a MNIST machine learning keras model that I built from the open-sourced MNIST dataset, which consists of **60000** training cases and **10000** test cases.

My machine learning model achieved roughly **99.1**% accuracy on the test cases. Currently, I am trying to build an android app that has a canvas allowing users to draw digits, which then are detected using my machine learning model.

However, the accuracy of the model in detecting scribbled digits on my phone is much lower. I want to formally test this by screenshotting the scribbled digits and putting it through my model.

The screenshots are of jpg format, encoded in ARGB. I imported these images through the line:

```
    newarr = matplotlib.pyplot.imread(IMG_DIR+str(i+1)+'.jpg')
```

To resize the images to the desired dimensions **(28,28)**, I used

```
    newimg = tensorflow.image.resize(numpy.array(newarr),(28,28))
```

However, I got an error stating the following:

```
    ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type JpegImageFile).
```

I struggled to find a similar question involving the filetype JpegImageFile. My guess would be that the encoding of ARGB seemed to be a problem. The shape of the numpy array representing the Jpeg image file is **(449,449,3)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: I just found out that the offending jpg file had plt.imread() returning an object of type PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile rather than an ordinary array.

**EDIT 2**: It appears that this error only occurs for very specific (and luckily very few) images in my own prepared image set. My own prepared image set has roughly 200 images, and there are about 6-8 such offending jpg files that result in the error above. I am still not sure why plt.imread() will return an object of type PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile rather than numpy array, but those images can be replaced.

Comment: [`matplotlib.pyplot.imread`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) says the return value is a NumPy array.  If your input is a valid jpg file and `imread` returned something else, that could be a bug.  The matplotlib issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21474 looks relevant.  Note in particular this comment *"`imread` is a historical convenience function. If you plan to manipulate the images as numpy arrays, then indeed you will have to do something like `np.array(image)` first. Overall, I would not recommend using our `imread`.*"

Comment: Yes indeed all the inputs I passed into ***matplotlib.pyplot.imread*** are valid jpg files as I was able to open it with paint.net. However, for a few of those jpg images, ***imread*** returned an invalid image rather than a numpy array. For these cases, the line ***np.array(image)*** spat out an error, as did the line I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser would it be helpful if I attempt to find these specific images? I have deleted them, but I can look for them.

Comment: If you plan to file a bug report with matplotlib, then you will definitely need one of the "bad" files so you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser just curious, what would be the method in which I file a bug report? Can I expect any benefits by reporting a bug should the bug be a valid bug?